# How to split words into different columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am new to coding , recently started learning to code. Currently I am stuck in the process to split a column. Please help me

I have this dataframe

```
data = ['TOOK22JAN1515100HG','BOOK22FEB1643200GH','TOOK22MAR1742200HG']
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I want to split it into

```
0   TOOK22JAN1515100HG       TOOK    22-01-15   15100  HG
1   BOOK22FEB1643200GH       BOOK    22-02-16   43200  GH
2   TOOK22MAR1742200HG       TOOK    22-03-17   42200  HG
```

Really appreciate for taking your time and answering to my problem.

PS: this is just an example of option symbol which is combination of Index + date + strike + type (stock market)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.extract` to explode your string:

```
pattern = r'(?P<id>[A-Z]{4})(?P<date>\w{7})(?P<val>\d+)(?P<misc>[A-Z]{2})'

df = df.join(df[0].str.extract(pattern))

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(int)
print(df)

# Output
                    0    id       date    val misc
0  TOOK22JAN1515100HG  TOOK 2015-01-22  15100   HG
1  BOOK22FEB1643200GH  BOOK 2016-02-22  43200   GH
2  TOOK22MAR1742200HG  TOOK 2017-03-22  42200   HG
```

Comment: Thank you..
one more question 
any idea about this BOOKY2212031600CE, BANYTG2212031600CE?
result i want is BOOKY2212031600CE => BOOKY 22120 31600 CE and
BANYTG2212031600CE => BANYTG  22120  31600  CE

Comment: `22120` is not a date?

Comment: it is 2022-01-20

Comment: is it posible to convert 22120  to date? @Coralien

Comment: Yes but the format is more complicated to extract

Comment: Is the column `val` has always 5 digits?

Comment: not always, sometimes it comes in 22-Jan-17 format, but 5 digit is exception..
i can use try | else method for that